# Failing slow extrusion after upgrade to E3D hotend

Tags: extruder, slicing, extrusion

I recently upgraded to a E3D full hotend and I started to have problems with slowly printed parts. After I print first object and start next one, then the first layer has serious issue.

[image]

The first two test were extruded around 10mm/s, the right one around 15mm/s. The material is PLA (fillamentum.com) at temperature 210°C and nozzle diameter is 0.4mm. The Rebel II RepRap printer uses RAMPS with marlin firmware. I use Slic3r and Pronterface SW.

I didn't find answer in following troubleshooting guides:

- [Simplify3D - Print Quality Troubleshooting Guide](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/)
- [A visual Ultimaker troubleshooting guide](http://support.3dverkstan.se/article/23-a-visual-ultimaker-troubleshooting-guide)
- [RepRap - Print Troubleshooting Pictorial Guide](http://reprap.org/wiki/Print_Troubleshooting_Pictorial_Guide)
- [all3dp.com - 16 Common 3D Printing Problems (And Solutions)](https://all3dp.com/common-3d-printing-problems-and-their-solutions)

Do you have an idea what can cause this issue?

### Update

I did a new print, where I just heat the hotend and start printing immediately. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is it filled from below (which would mean it suddenly stop extruding well) or is it filled from above (which would mean it suddenly start extruding well)?

Comment: Under extrusion, ususally caused by going too fast vs your temp, or you have a clog / loose filament drive

Comment: What kind of e3d hotend is used?

Comment: It's e3d v5 hotend.

Answer (score 2):

I bet your old and new extruders have different hobbed pulley/bolt effective diameter.
It looks like your new extruder has smaller hobbed diameter that's why it pushes too less material.

In MatterControl application there is a slider which allows user to tuneup extrude ratio on the fly (while printing). You coud check it so it would confirm the issue.

In Slic3r you could go to

Printer Settings > Advanced > Extrusion width

and experiment with it (especially with Default extrusion width)

Both (Slic3r and MC) could answer your question if it's extrusion ratio issue. If you confirm that - you can proceed with calibration. Here is method to [calibrate extruder flow](http://reprap.org/wiki/Triffid_Hunter's_Calibration_Guide#E_steps) and [general calibration article here](http://reprap.org/wiki/Calibration).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did calibration with the new hotend, where I also have changed the motor to lighter 1.8° version instead of original 0.9°. To be sure I didn't forget anything I will recheck the calibration.

Comment: Before considering any calibration you should compute the exact ideal steps per mm from the mechanical properties.

Answer (score 2):

> After I print first object and start next one, then the first layer has serious issue.

Are you leaving the hotend on between prints? If you leave an E3D hotend heated up while it's not printing, heat will slowly migrate up the heatbreak and start softening the filament there, which will subsequently become stuck. You should turn off the heat immediately after finishing your print (or, ideally, just have your end G-code contain a command to turn the hotend off).

Comment: Yes I am leaving hotend on. But the first object is pretty small, so I would expect to print first layer without problem. I will test this behavior.